# Spring Data - item in database, but cannot be found by entityManager

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-transactions

I'm experiencing an issue where entity cannot be found despite it's present in the database. It's created by another service via Remote Procedure Call and persisted after the invocation, but `entityManager` is simply unable to return the entity object - it returns `null` instead.

I've tried calling `entityManager.clear()` before obtaining the item, but it didn't help whatsoever.
I've also tried `entityManager.refresh(entityManager.find(Item.class, itemId))` and got only an error, since `find` method returns null anyway.

Please enlighten me - why am I unable to fetch the item from database even after clearing the persistence cache?

```
@Transactional
class ItemService {

    @Autowired
    ItemCreationRPCService itemCreationRPCService;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    Item createItem(CreateItemRequest request) {
        Long itemId = itemCreationRPCService.create(request); // persisted and present in the database, returns id of created item
        Item item = entityManager.find(Item.class, itemId); // returns null
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: @M.Deinum there's a whole other microservice responsible for creating the `Item` - hence the RPC call.

Comment: If you can access the database locally without going through the other microservice, you are doing microservices wrong, databases should not be shared!. Hence are you sure you are looking at **the same** database (as I actually doubt that).

Comment: Well, I'm aware that in the perfect world of microservices databases should not be shared, nevertheless the question is not about the architecture. And yes, I'm 100% sure my applications are connected to the same database.

Comment: Consider having more faith in a questioner - it **is** the same database and item is persisted.

Comment: Well apparently it isn't else it would yield a result. So something isn't as you think it is. Either the database, the mapping, looking at a different table etc.